# Как разобраться с позиционирование элементов со свойством transform-style: preserve-3d в Mozille?

Tags: css, css3

Доброго дня есть сайт [wise-side.ru/demo/olympic](http://wise-side.ru/demo/olympic), на первом экране этого сайта присутствуют три 3 блока с текстом , которые сделаны с помощью transform-style: preserve-3d, для того что когда выполнялось вращение(интервал через 8сек) была видимость объема блоков. Отображение во всех браузерах адекватное, т.е как и должно быть по дизайну [joxi.ru/Drlb0RgS41vRB2](http://joxi.ru/Drlb0RgS41vRB2)
А вот в мозилле каким-то образом средний блок позиционируется над остальными выше [joxi.ru/a2XKXEztyO1zxm](http://joxi.ru/a2XKXEztyO1zxm). Z-index здесь не помогает....
Не могу понять почему так происходит и как решить эту проблему , если кто может поделится опытом или сталкивался с подобным , пожалуйста подскажите что делать с этим?

Answer (score 1):

```
transform: translateZ(0px);
```

на `.titleBoxTop` и `.titleBoxBottom`